# Activity NoClassDefFoundError using Android Studio

Tags: android

*Note*: This is not a missing class in a jar, so don't rush to mark this as a duplicate.
I'm porting a big project from eclipse to **Android Studio**. I finally succeeded to see my SplashActivity on screen, but I fail to get the MainActivity which is launched after my SplashActivity. I'm getting the following error on runtime:

```
> 06-13 14:42:30.176 12389-12389/com.totalboox E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main Process: com.totalboox, PID: 12389 
>    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.androidcore.android.main.MainActivity$4
>    at com.androidcore.android.main.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:587)
>    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

MainActivity is declared in the Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.androidcore.android.main.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.totalboox.MESSAGE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The code at MainActivity:587

// Pushwoosh lib integration (see https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/native-android-sdk-integration/)

```
BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new RegisterBroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onRegisterActionReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        checkMessage(intent);
    }
};
```

Where RegisterBroadcastReceiver is from an external lib (pushwoosh) handling notifications.

The code in SplashActivity  starting MainActivity:

```
Intent mainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
mainActivity.putExtra("deep_link_book_id", deepLinkBookId);
startActivity(mainActivity); 
finish();
```

Googling this I found people having this problem with a jar. In my case MainActivity.java is one of my source modules, and its package name is 
`package com.androidcore.android.main;` exactly as declared in the Manifest.
The project is built of 4 subprojects. SplashActivity & MainActivity are in the same subproject.

I've spent countless hours on this. I tried: Clean, Rebuild, Invalidate Cache and Restart - nothing helped.
Anyone can advise how to stop this nightmare? Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Post the code related to MainActivity:587

Comment: `MainActivity$4` typically means an inner class, possibly anonymous, of your Activity

Comment: actionandroid -> action android, categoryandroid -> category android

Comment: Try cleaning your project, rebuild and see what happens

Comment: Please post the code how and where you are starting `MainActivity`.

Comment: Post the complete stack trace so we'll know how and when it's thrown

Comment: • @Fondesa, I posted the code at MainActivity:587. Thanks!
• Shadab, I posted the code in SplashActivity  starting MainActivity. Thanks!
• Cricket_007 , you are right, it is an anonymous class. Thanks. Does this point how to solve the issue?
• Stepan, the missing spaces are in the manifest (pasting mistake). Thx.
• Eevincible, as I wrote I tried clean & rebuild more times than I can count, but thanks.

Comment: @Kai - Complete error stack trace posted. Thanks!

Comment: @Cricket_007 , you are right, it is an anonymous class. Thanks. Does this point how to solve the issue?

Comment: @senti I think the issue is that  RegisterBroadcastReceiver doesn't exist for the compiled apk. How do you integrate the lib?

Comment: I'm not really sure... Is progaurd enabled? You could open the apk file in a program that opens ZIP files to check the classes that get compiled into it. If all else fails, making your own class file to extend the BroadcastReceiver might work.

Comment: @Kai RegisterBroadcastReceiver exists in the jar that is in 'androidcore' lib folder. From Android Studio I can't see if it's in the apk.

Comment: @Cricket_007 proguard should not be the issue since I'm using the default Run (which should be debug). Gradle console also shows `:androidCore:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies` (There are some proguard msgs in Gradle console but they remained even after I commented out proguardFile' command from Gradle). 
When opening the apk in zip I see only one file, but this is a viewing problem.
I'll try first to comment out the integration with the library.
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be use this for your intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

if your package name is:  (may be `com.androidcore.android`? - please check)

```
com.androidcore.android.main
```

then use for name:   (if package name `com.androidcore.android` then use `.main.MainActivity` )

```
android:name=".MainActivity"
```

actually best name for package is your domain reverse:

```
com.yourdomain.yourprojectname
```

keep this in memory to be cool )

Comment: The intent filter action is sent internally by the app, so it is not android.intent.action.MAIN  
MainActivity's category is not LAUNCHER (the launcher is SplashActivity)  
The package name is correct. It does not start with `com.yourdomain`. Refactoring to this name didn't work. I suspect this is a side effect of the eclipse-to-AndroidStudio porting tool.